# swap seller name in product view page based on quantity

Tags: magento

we have marketplace multi vendor/seller site.

we are displaying multiple sellers on product view page.

initially one  Product is uploaded by seller "kidsdial4" , than same product is assigned by another seller "kidsdial6".

than in product view page, we are displaying both seller names like [this](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/assign.html)

on top you can see  seller kidsdial4

[image]

on bottom you can see seller kidsdial 6

[image]

here `seller kidsdial4 have "zero" stock` [out-of-stock ] for that product.

& kidsdial6 seller have quantity for that product.

so i want to display kidsdial 6 seller on top , kidsdial 4 should display on bottom.

```
<?php $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); ?>
<?php if(count($this->sellerNewProductList())!=0 || count($this->sellerUsedProductList())!=0): ?>
    <div class="wk_mp_design" id="seller-list" style="clear:both">
        <div class="block block-account">
            <div class="head block-title">
                <strong>
                    <span class="wk_new_tab list_active_tab" for="seller-list-new"><?php echo $this->__('Sold By')." ".count($this->sellerNewProductList())."" ." Sellers "; ?></span>
                    <!-- <span class="wk_tab_seperator"></span>
                    <span class="wk_used_tab" for="seller-list-used"><?php echo $this->__('Used')." (".count($this->sellerUsedProductList()).")";?></span> -->
                </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="seller-list" id="seller-list-new">
                <?php if(count($this->sellerNewProductList())==0): ?>
                    <div class="fieldset wk_mp_fieldset">
                        <div class="wk_emptymsg">
                            <?php echo $this->__('No New Product Available') ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="title">
                        <span class="lable profile"><?php echo $this->__('Sellers');?></span>
                        <span class="lable comment"><?php echo $this->__('Delivered By');?></span>
                        <span class="lable price"><?php echo $this->__('Price');?></span>
                        <span class="lable addto"><?php echo $this->__('');?></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php foreach($this->sellerNewProductList() as $seller): ?>
                        <?php
                            $userlist=Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection();
                            $userlist->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$seller->getSellerId()));
                            foreach($userlist as $user){
                                $profileurl=$user->getProfileurl();
                                $logo=$user->getLogopic();
                            }
                        ?>
```

complete code of `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/mpassignproduct/sellerlist.phtml` => http://pasted.co/13849662

```
app/code/local/Webkul/Mpassignproduct/Block/Sellerlist.php

<?php

class Webkul_Mpassignproduct_Block_Sellerlist extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout() {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function sellerNewProductList() {
        $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
        $collection=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('flag',array('eq'=>'1'))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_condition', array('eq'=>'new'));
        $collection->setOrder("price",ASC);
        return $collection;
    }

    public function sellerUsedProductList() {
        $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_condition',array('eq'=>'used'))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('flag',array('eq'=>'1'));
        $collection->setOrder("price",ASC);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort the collection `sellerNewProductList()` by quantity (highest to lowest) in your block

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints, can you please update the answer with code.

Comment: Kindly share the code for getting this `sellerNewProductList()`, I can then help with the sort

Comment: Please check updated question, i posted code to get `sellerNewProductList()`

Comment: Checking your code above, in `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/mpassignproduct/sellerlist.phtml` that is only for this block here - https://monosnap.com/file/JnNNNhvShhqj4AXVWX2G90W9fQ2EJ and its been sorted by qty > o from the collection method `sellerNewProductList()`. that is why its returning only seller - kidsdial6. Can you share the template file and block for this section here - https://monosnap.com/file/nneIrBP9zZtbWNzUP1TlJJLBwY9O6z.

Comment: we wrote those code in view.phtml = > http://pastebin.com/ahNwEYZN

soon i will post code related to blocks

Comment: please check other block related codes

mpassignproductlist.php = > http://pasted.co/d70be2cc  & mpassignproduct.php

Comment: we are using this extension : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace-seller-price-comparison.html

Comment: Going through view.phtml, I can see 'kidsdial4 ' is displayed on top as the product owner which was fetched from `$rowsocial = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($productowner['userid']);`

Comment: i added here app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object ` in line : `if ($sellerProductInfo->getSize() == 0) {`

Comment: i tried like this [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111457/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getsize-on-a-non-object) , now there is no error. but still out-of-stock product is displaying above only.

Comment: You shouldn't really write directly into app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php but extend it, however to get this problem resolved, aside the product showing do you still see seller name on top i.e 'kidsdial4'. Also, I need information as regards:
1- the structure of 'mpassignproduct' table
2- Does that table contain both the product owner and other sellers assigned to a product information
3- Is $productowner['userid'] the same as seller_id or sellerId in mpassignproduct table.

Comment: this is demo site, okay as you said in live site i will extend it to local folder. please visit here : http://prnt.sc/au3myq]

Comment: we are using this [extension](https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-Seller-Price-Comparison.html) for my knowledge 

this table contain information related to assigned sellers & their products. also mostly $productowner['userid'] is different 

than sellerId in mpassignproduct table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109530/discussion-between-hardayborlar-and-spylh9999ggr).